# Exception happened during processing of request from IOS Device

Tags: python, ios, django, sockets, django-rest-framework

I am trying to play a video on an iOS device. When I tried to play i got the following error:

```
[27/Apr/2015 06:59:30] "GET /media/2015/04/VID_20150327_112644.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 18

 Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.1.230', 51412)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/likewise-open/ZEALOUSYS/manesh/virtualenv/tracks/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 129, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.1.230', 51412)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/likewise-open/ZEALOUSYS/manesh/virtualenv/tracks/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 129, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
```

The video file of all formats is working perfectly in all browsers and Android devices. When I try to access it from an iOS device. It gives me the above error. As you can see in error, first it is giving me response as 200 and then there is broken pipe. What does this broken pipe even mean? Just FYI, I have already posted a question stating that I can't play video on iOS devices, I am now posting a new question because I found this error in my terminal.

How do i fix this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The broken pipe error has probably nothing to do with the iOS device not playing the video file. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7913160/1644198 for information about the broken pipe error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is beacause django is handling your media files not apache.Try by changing you configuration in server.

For example inside your apache2 edit example.com.conf file add following lines so that apache will serve media files.

```
**Alias /media /your project path/media**
```

Sometimes this may fix this issue.